# Downvoting and Closing of a Good Question

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, down-votes

[This](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/219138/is-sln-zx-generated-by-en-zx) seems to be a perfectly good (i.e. interesting and nontrivial) question that was downvoted and closed for mysterious reasons.  As far as I can tell, the main objection is that the author mistakenly wrote $GL$ instead of $SL$ in the body (but not the title) of the question.  Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Why is the post not yet fixed? A question that is unclear can and should be closed until it is fixed. The question is clearly unclear as it asks two different questions, pretending to ask just one.

Comment: And by the way how to reconcile "But GL(n,Z[x]) is just matrices with determinant 1 or −1, so it should be true for both, no?" with what you imply?

Comment: @quid:  The way to reconcile it is to observe that the OP clearly made a silly mistake that is tangential to the main question, and to ignore that mistake.

Comment: What is the main question? You imply there is a typo, but from the comment it seems OP at least also (maybe only?) cares about GL.

Comment: Steven, if you are confident that you know what the OP intended, would you do the honors and fix any typos? It would likely hasten a reopening, unless there are other objections.

Comment: Todd:  Done.  I was hesitating to edit for fear of rendering the comment thread incomprehensible, but on second thought, I think my priorities were misplaced.

Comment: Steven -- thanks! Much appreciated.